# Can I use AVCaptureDevicePosition to toggle between front and back camera inputs?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, ios9, avcapturesession

Is it as easy as:

```
-(IBAction)switchCameraTapped: (id)sender{
if (AVCaptureDevicePosition == 1) {
    AVCaptureDevicePosition == 2;
} else if (AVCaptureDevicePosition ==2){
    AVCaptureDevicePosition == 1;}
}
```

?

Do I have to create a new capture session or remove any existing inputs?

Comment: What are these 1 and 2?

Comment: enum {
   AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified = 0,
   AVCaptureDevicePositionBack  = 1,
   AVCaptureDevicePositionFront = 2
};

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not that simple - the position is a read-only property on `AVCaptureDevice`:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) AVCaptureDevicePosition position;
```

You don't need to destroy the capture session, you can instead call

```
[session stopRunning];
```

and reconfigure the inputs with `removeInput` and `addInput`.

Don't forget to call `startRunning` when you've finished.